# Python axhline, title and axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, axis-labels

I am trying to plot a horizontal line over another plot using matplotlib. Everything works except the title and axis labels never show up. How does this work?

*Edit-sorry, code looks sort of like this:
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    n=100

```
plt.axhline(y=n, label='Old')
plt.plot([5, 6, 7, 8], [100, 110, 115, 150], 'ro', label='New')
plt.xlabel=('Example x')
plt.ylabel=('Example y')
plt.title=('Example Title')
plt.legend()
plt.axis([0,10,50,150])
plt.show()
```

Everything shows up normally just no title and no axis labels. The legend is there.

Comment: You'll need to show some code with the observed and expected output.

Comment: `plt.xlabel`, `plt.title`, etc. are functions you call, not attributes to be assigned to.

Comment: you need to remove the `=` signs as in:
`plt.xlabel("Example x")`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axhline(y=n, label='Old')
ax.plot([5, 6, 7, 8], [100, 110, 115, 150], 'ro', label='New')

ax.set_xlabel('Example x')
ax.set_ylabel('Example y')
ax.set_title('Example Title')

ax.legend()
ax.set_xticks([0,10,50,150])
ax.set_yticks([0,10,50,150])

plt.show()
```

Comment: +1 for using the OO interface!  I normally use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)`.

Comment: what does the `111` do? how is it different from doing e.g. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True, tight_layout=True)`?